# Ant Design: How to make items have equal heights

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use Ant Design in my react project. When I use the Row, I want all the columns in the Row have the same height.

What happens now:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, the Ant Row [type](https://ant.design/components/grid/#Row) property with the value **flex** will help you achieve this.

Try something like this :

```
<Row type="flex">  
   <Col xs={12}>
   </Col>
   <Col xs={12}>
   </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: I try flex but it does not help

Comment: Here is a codepen with the same. Seems to work fine. Let me know if this is not what you were looking for. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYJKMa

Comment: Please update the answer!

Comment: Deprecated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Seems `type="flex"` is no longer supported.
I've just set `height="100%"` to Col's first child.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me `display:flex` to every `Col` worked.